# How to position gps point on svg scheme of building?

Tags: d3.js, svg, gps, geojson, topojson

I have an indoor map of a building in svg and this is an only scheme of a building, there is no google maps or any other maps. But I need positioning (navigation) by gps coordinates in this scheme.

There is no problem to get coordinates value by gps. The question is how to set current position point on the right place in indoor svg scheme?

I think I found solution to use GeoJSON(TopoJSON) and D3.js. But how can you connect full building scheme to GeoJSON borders of building only?

I'll appreciate any help, maybe existing well-tried way or code examples.

Thanks!